# Render specific react component based on the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/search" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>;
}
```

**Home.js**

```
function Home() {
    const location = useLocation();
    return (
        <div className="home">
            <Component1 />
            {location.pathname === "/home" && <Feed />}
            {location.pathname === "/search" && <Search />}
            <Component2 />
        </div>
    );
}
```

This works perfectly as I want to render the `Feed` or `Search` component depending on the URL.

But, I want to know is it okay to use `location.pathname` or is there any better alternative?

Comment: why aren't you using react routers?

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do in more detail? How can you be on `/search` if your are rendering the `Home` component on `/home`?

Comment: @AlexWayne The `Home` component should probably be named `MainLayout` or something, and various pages share this layout.

Comment: @DavidCallanan Ohh yes. Should rename the component. Am terrible at naming components. Hehe!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/home" component={() => <Home showFeed/>} />
        <Route exact path="/search" component={() => <Home showSearch/>} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>;
}
```

**Home.js**

```
function Home(props) {
    const location = useLocation();
    return (
        <div className="home">
            <Component1 />
            {props.showFeed && <Feed />}
            {props.showSearch && <Search />}
            <Component2 />
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

This allows you to abstract away the `Home` component's dependency on any routing mechanism, and simply allows you to control whether certain elements appear or not from outside this component.

Comment: @zx01 Great. Consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68412816/1541397) if you'd like more flexibility (if you are always only displaying one of the components at a time).

Comment: This will re-render the entire `Home` component. on url change. Is there any way in which only the `Feed` and `Search` components re-render based on url and the other components (Component 1 & 2) don't render and remain as it is?

Comment: @zx01 What's wrong with a re-render? I'm pretty sure (correct me if I'm wrong) that the state will remain intact between re-renders, so there should be no issue.

Comment: There is nothing wrong. But am just curious whether there is any way to do that?

Comment: @zx01 No I don't think so. But even when a re-render occurs on the virtual dom, React will do a diff, so the elements shouldn't actually get re-created in the real dom.

Comment: Ohh okay. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use  `home` component as layout. This can be highly recommended. You can rename your `home` component as `Layout`. This is more flexible way.

```
function Home() {
    const location = useLocation();
    return (
        <div className="home">
            <Component1 />
             { props.children }
            <Component2 />
        </div>
    );
}
```

In your `app.js` modify like bellow

```
function App() {
  <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/home">
          <Home>
           <Feed />
          </Home>
         </Route>
        <Route exact path="/search">
          <Home>
           <Search/>
          </Home>
         </Route>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>;
}
```

Comment: its glad to help